# Remove elements in a chart generated with highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working on a new website using highchart. But I have a little issue with how it looks / is setup.

I'm wondering if it is possible to remove the legend "Tokyo, New York, Berlin, London" on the right side of the image? I would like to add a discription myself, and remove the existing one.

[image: the generated chart]

Any Suggestions on how I can remove, modify or hide this? (But I want to keep the lines in the graph.)
 (It also take up unnecessary space on the website)

Comment: use firebug.... get the class and use `remove()` or `hide()`... posting some of ur code will be easier to us...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can [Here is working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/67HQj/). You have to set

```
 legend: {
            enabled:false
        },
```

in highcharts code.

Answer (score 1):

In the basic-line sample provided if you view the source and edit the below Javascript you can edit/remove the line series labels aswell as the actual data values.

```
series: [{
    name: '**New Name**',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
}, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
}, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
}, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
}]
```